# ElasticSearch get distinct all values of one field with Java High Level Client 7.x

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I want to get all values of a field from elasticsearch using java high level client.

I'm using following code:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest =  new SearchRequest(index);
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery(field, "*"));
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
SearchResponse response = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I want to get the values DISTINCT (like select distinct field from table), if it's possible.

Comment: Fairly straight forward, use aggregations, refer: https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-get-unique-values-for-a-field-in-elasticsearch for an example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works with aggregations.